# JQUERY, Compare two Text Blocks, and then animate only the new text

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery

I have two blocks of text

Text Block 1 - Currently displayed on the page:
"Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa"

But now Block 1 on the backend is: "Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsaadskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasdadskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsaadskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasdadskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsaadskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsaadskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsaadskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa"

I'd like to update the original Block 1 that's on the page, with the Block 2 that's on the server to the page.

And I'd like to append, and not flash the entire block. So only the new stuff is flashed.

Any ideas on how to do this in JQUERY?

Comment: Could you put those in quote blocks to aid readability?

Comment: Best sample text evar...

Answer (score 3):

Well, this doesn't do the flash, but it does show how you would focus the flash on the new content. I've colored it yellow for visibility.

The old content is in a span with class "old". The new content gets placed in a span with class "new".

See it in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/P2T8Q/

HTML

```
<span id="page">Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa</span>
```

CSS

```
​.new {
    background: yellow;
}​
​
```

jQuery

```
var backend = "Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsaadskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasdadskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsaadskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasdadskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsaadskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsaadskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsaadskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa";

var page = $('#page').text();

backend = backend.replace(page, function(str){ return '<span class="old">' + str + '</span><span class="new">' });

$('#page').html(backend + '</span>');
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to avoid string slinging, do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/P2T8Q/1/

jQuery

```
var backend = "Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsaadskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasdadskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsaadskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasdadskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsaadskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsaadskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsaadskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa Ahd Hd ahaSdjdajs dadjs jasd adskadskl1lksad klasd klasd dsa";

var page = $('#page').text();

var regex = new RegExp('^(' + page + ')(.+)');

backend.replace(regex, function(str,p1,p2){var old = $('<span class="old" />').text(p1); var updated = $('<span class="new" />').text(p2); $('#page').empty().append(old).append(updated); });
```